# should I mark a method as const if it does not modify the instance of a class itself, but an external mechanism embedded in the class?

Tags: c++

I use epoll for prototyping a little TCP server, just for pedagogic purposes.
epoll has a function `int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);`. When used with the operation (`op`)  `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`, the function add the fd to the list of fd watched by epoll.

On my side, I have written a wrapper class for epoll in C++, which provides some useful functions, including `Epoll::add_connection(int fd)`. This function call `epoll_ctl()` and add the fd passed as parameter in the epoll instance.

So, my question:

`Epoll::add_connection(int fd)` doesn't modify an instance of my class, no attributes are modified. But, since my class represent more or less epoll itself, in a way the instance is modified...

**Should I mark this function const or not ?**

Comment: I would go with not. As you say you are modifying the state the `epfd` connects to inside the kernel. I'm not sure what operation on a epoll wrapper I would mark as const at all. I don't think epoll has any operation that doesn't modify some state.

Comment: You should make it const, as it can be executed with a const object of your class. That some data are modified somewhere else is not an argument as this will more or less happen everytime. A function which did not modify anything is useless :-)

Answer (score 2):

General consideration: I'd rather look at what the function *logically* does: It does change the internal representation, even though in given case no embedded member actually is modified.

If for whatever reason need for arises later on (like additionally storing the file descriptors in a `std::vector` – or at least remembering the number of file descriptors stored) you'd need to change the signature – and then existing code relying on a `const` object would break!